# How do I calculate a distinct count of a distinct dimension in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

As seen in the image link below, I am trying to calculate the 3rd column above and add it to my data source.

I understand that it uses the COUNTD (Discrete Count) however I can't get it to work correctly. What calculation would I use to add the 3rd column to my data source using the first and second columns?

I tried { FIX [App] : COUNTD(Rule)} but that's solely returning 1 for every row since it's not aggregating based on the the number of discrete rules for each app.

[Click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ecIa.jpg)

Comment: What tool are you using to modify the data source?

Comment: @Andy I'm not using any other tools, solely using Tableau. The goal is to import an excel sheet from a web based server directly into Tableau, then modify the data source from there. I'm aware that this may not be possible to this extent however.

Answer (score 0):

I duplicated your data and was able to get it to work with:

```
{ FIXED [App]: COUNTD([Rule])}
```

except that it is grouping your App and Rule columns, but I would think that would be okay? See image:

[image: Count Sample]